# Google Developer Console API Manager - Quota history 'empty'

Tags: api, google-maps, quota

Since Monday, when Google changed the UI for the Developer Console API Manager, the Quota Usage History (for all but the JavaScript API) shows no data!

From the new Dashboard, clicking on the APIs now takes you to a page with 2 tabs - 'Overview' and 'Quotas'.  The 'Overview' displays data for all APIs as expected, but the 'Quotas' tab only displays the data for the JavaScript API - all others have no data to show (the previous version worked just fine showing the last 30 days of usage).  Before anyone asks the obvious question, yes, my enabled APIs are all in constant use so there is data there!

Does anyone else have this problem?

[Dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lSDs.png)

[JavaScript API Overview (Showing Traffic)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xs43o.png)

[JavaScript API Quotas (Showing Quota History)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4i4kY.png)

[Geocoding API Overview (Showing Traffic)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCMWl.png)

[Geocoding API Quotas (NOT showing Quota History - it used to!)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ium39.png)

Comment: I don't really understand your question, can you please provide some screenshot for your question, because when I checked my own Dashboard, everything works fine.

Comment: Everyone I try to contact at Google says I'm contacting the wrong 'department'.  They all keep telling me that this forum is monitored by Google tech staff!  Can no one help?

Comment: try to disable the Geocoding API, then enable it again

Comment: Hi KENdi - thanks for the help!  I've just tried your suggestion but still no joy!

Comment: I tried it to my GDC, but mine is working without any issue. I will still try to find out the caused of this. I will go back to you if I found out the solution.

Comment: Hey, similar problem here. Did you found the solution?

Comment: Hi kabaer - no - it just seemed to right itself!  Just one thing I noticed though is that while the JavaScript API only shows 'Map loads', the others now split into 3 sections - 'Premium plan web service queries', 'Premium plan JavaScript API queries' and 'Queries' so its necessary to scroll down if you aren't on a Premium plan!

Answer (score 0):

You can also reach the quota page by going to `IAM & Admin > Quotas > Select project"` and then select the API for which you want to see the quota.